# Convert a date object into unix timestamp in R?

Tags: r, timestamp, tidyverse, unix-timestamp, lubridate

Usually we see people converting [unix-timestamps](/questions/tagged/unix-timestamps) into date objects - is it possible to do the reverse instead?

For example, given the following date

`12-02-2019 00:00:00`

convert this into unix time achieving the following value:

`1549929600`

Is this possible within [r](/questions/tagged/r)? Potentially there could be something in [lubridate](/questions/tagged/lubridate) or [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) but I have not figured it out yet. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer as simply:

```
as.numeric(as.POSIXct("12-02-2019 00:00:00 EST"))
```